# Camunda: How to login with spring security?

Tags: spring-security, camunda

Sorry for this naive question.

I generated a project using start.camunda.com, with spring security.

I do see spring security pwd in console. When I try to use admin/, I get a message password is invalid. Should I use some other userid/pwd?

The starter
[image]

The app config:
[image]

The cmd line spring security pwd
[image]

Login fail
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) On the form-based login page provided by Spring Boot you can use the generated credentials as you tried above and as described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#servlet-hello-boot-dependencies
In you example above this would be:
user: **user**
password: the generated password you highlighted on the console

b) This gets you past the spring security login, but the project would still be missing the SSO config for Camunda. To make this work quickly you can copy the packages

- config
- filter

from 
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/springboot-security-sso/src/main/java/com/camunda/demo

c) if you copy those folders into the generated starter project then the package name will differ, so you need to adjust
**com.example.workflow.config.WebAppSecurityConfig line 33**
to reflect the changed package name:

```
filterRegistration.setInitParameters(Collections.singletonMap("authentication-provider", "com.example.workflow.filter.webapp.SpringSecurityAuthenticationProvider"));
```

d) as a result of the new security configuration the credentials from a) will not exist anymore. Instead you can now use the credentials defined in 
**com.example.workflow.config.SecurityConfig**
For instance access http://localhost:8080/ using the credentials *john/john* or *demo/demo*

---

Also see: https://camunda.com/best-practices/securing-camunda/

Comment: Hi Rob I tried the steps you mentioned but I am not getting any login screen and getting error : There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401) .  I am using Camunda version 7.17 . I tried the same after cloning the git repo  https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/springboot-security-sso also but same error there. My ultimate aim is to implement sso via SAML in okta .

Comment: To help I would need to see more details. Maybe open your own question and share more info. Exact setup, possibly code on github, log file...

Comment: Hi Rob , I did not change even single line of code in about example. I simply run the project. It simply fails with 401 error. BTW I was able to setup okta and run with camunda. But can't run basic auth : facepalm :)